# How to remove ApiUtil.java from openApi geneate task with openapi-generator-gradle-plugin:4.3.0

Tags: java, openapi-generator

I have am using `openapi-generator-gradle-plugin:4.3.0` to generate the api and models from a `openApi-generate.yaml` file. I have set `skipDefaultInterface: "true"` in configOptions, the default implementation of interfaces is not generated and `ApiUtil.java` is not used anywhere. (The default implementations used `ApiUtil.java`)

What I want is to remove (disable the generation of) `ApiUtil.java` from generated_sources, as it is not used in code, and its default code is creating security-issues in pipeline as well.

What I have tried: I have tried adding different options::

1. `supportingFilesConstrainedTo = []`
2. `supportingFiles = ""`
3. `supportingFilesToGenerate = ""`
4. `apiFilesConstrainedTo = []`

But I haven't been able to remove this file from being generated. I went through this: [OpenApi generation Customization](https://openapi-generator.tech/docs/customization/), but looks like it is not applicable for the given version.

Current gradle buildscript looks as:

```
task generateTask(type: org.openapitools.generator.gradle.plugin.tasks.GenerateTask) {
    generatorName = "spring"
    inputSpec = "$projectDir/src/main/resources/specs/openApi-generate.yaml"
    outputDir = "$buildDir/generated-sources"
    apiPackage = "com.example.openapi.api"
    modelPackage = "com.example.openapi.model"
    generateModelDocumentation = false
    generateApiDocumentation = false
    generateModelTests = false
    generateApiTests = false
    configOptions = [
        dateLibrary: "java8",
        interfaceOnly: "true",
        serializableModel: "true",
        skipDefaultInterface: "true"
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answering my own question. I had to do following things:

1. Increase Open Api version in build.gradle. This is important becuase it was not supported in older versions:

`id "org.openapi.generator" version 5.3.1`

2. Inside build script provide following options

```
globalProperties = [
            apis      : ""
]
```

Comment: If i do this the model package is also not generated anymore (generator version 7.1)

Answer (score 1):

A bit late but always good to give a good answer.

You have to use the configOption `skipDefaultInterface` but you also need to set the property `generateSupportingFiles` to false (which is NOT one of the configOptions but goes directly under `configuration`)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I was able to remove ApiUtil with following settings:

```
openApiGenerate {
...
  globalProperties.set(mapOf("generateSupportingFiles" to "false", "apis" to ""))
```

Comment: If i do this the model package is also not generated anymore (generator version 7.1)

Answer (score -1):

Place generateSupportingFiles: "false" under configOptions.

Comment: there is no such option.

Comment: if i add the option in the current gradle plugin, it does not work. -for me the way using globalProperties is working

Comment: just checked my config. i used org.openapitools:openapi-generator-maven-plugin:5.4.0, not gradle, sorry. anyway i believe this is helpful info.